# How to loop through Roblox studio to find all the humanoid and choose which is the closest one to chase? (For an Npc)

Tags: loops, lua, game-engine, game-development, roblox

I want to make a Npc that chases the nearest humanoids (Npc or Player) and I'm not sure how to loop through workspace to do that.

I tried experimenting with for loops but I'm a noob and I need help.
Ok i figured it out but One problem though, I use this script to check whether the npc is close and if its less than 3 to damage the other fighter... `(fighter.HumanoidRootPart.Position.X. - closestEnemy.HumanoidRootPart.Position.X).Magnitude < 3`...but when it runs and the npcs chase each other and they Touch each other it prints 55 or 30 even though they are legit touching each other.

Answer (score 1):

Get the distance between you and the entity and check if its smaller. Its very simple math

Comment: Thanks, One problem though, I use this script to check whether the npc is close and if its less than 3 to damage the other fighter... (fighter.HumanoidRootPart.Position.X.Magnitude - closestEnemy.HumanoidRootPart.Position.X).Magnitude < 3...but when it runs and the npcs chase each other and they Touch each other it prints 55 or 30 even though they are legit touching each other.